# how can I show log on onclick of a button in android?

Tags: android

Trying to add just `onClick` function run in the android studio. I want to show text message in log by clicking on my button but the desired result doesn't come.

Please help.

activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:onClick="clickFunction"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="139dp"
    android:text="Button" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

mainActivity.java file

```
 package com.example.jewelcsebu.hellotest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public void clickFunction(View view){

     Log.i("Info", "Button Pressed");

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
}
```

I just made `onClick` function to run. but this given error below:

```
2018-12-06 19:40:12.700 1808-1808/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2018-12-06 19:40:19.252 1716-1745/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2018-12-06 19:40:37.061 1890-1911/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

Comment: Try `android:onClick="clickFunction"` instead of `tools:onClick`

Comment: it shows the following error

Comment: its doesn't work

Comment: Your log message implies that you want to invoke your `clickFunction` when the button is pressed. At the moment you are listening to clicks in your root layout. Move `android:onClick="clickFunction"` into the button's layout in your XML.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace **tools:onClick** with **android:onClick**
And I recommend you to put **android:onClick** inside the Button element like this:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="139dp"
android:onClick="clickFunction"
android:text="Button" />
```

Or use the OnClickListener Callback like this:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickFunction();
    }
});

public void clickFunction(View view){

     Log.i("Info", "Button Pressed");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I just import class (import android.widget.Button;)

Like this :
 import android.widget.Button;

and I didn't change anything to log.i(tag: "info", msg: "Button Pressed!");

it works for me